# ConstraintLayout make View Height x % of Sibling

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-percentrelativelayout

I was wondering if it's possible with Constraintlayout to achieve the following:

[image]

I have an Image with a fixed Ratio (2:1) and want it to overlay with a gradient, which should start from the bottom of the Image and top align it to 50% of the Image height.
As far as I could see it is not possible.
Using a Guideline does not work, as it can only be placed with Percentage to the Parent/Layout
Using `weight` is only possible in Chains, but as I need to overlay both views chains cannot be used, right?

Answer (score 1):

you can achieved this like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="2:1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/View_Top"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="4:1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/View_Bottom"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="4:1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/View_Top"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark" />



    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

here imageView is set in 2:1 ratio and 2 extra view set in above Imageview where View_Top is transparent and View_Bottom is bottom half of imageview so you can set your gradient in View_Bottom.

In below image background color is gray and your color can replace in View_Bottom color

[image]
hope it will help you..!

Comment: Thanks, that would work. Would be great to align `Guidlines` to other views as well to get rid of the top spacing view. I guess using a `Space` could save the drawing of the transparent view (if it's processed actually, not sure about that)

Comment: yes, you may add space also intends of transparent view

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you want to have a gradient layer over your image. You can do that by setting a foreground drawable to your image:

```
android:foreground="@drawable/gradient-layer"
```

and then have your *gradient-layer.xml* something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:endColor="@color/transparent"
        android:startColor="@color/color1"
        android:type="linear" />
    <corners android:radius="0dp"/>
</shape>
```

Additionally you can add a middle color to the gradient if you need it to be more specific

```
android:centerColor="@color/color2"
```

Comment: The special requirement here is, that the gradient just covers half the image height. I'm aware of putting a gradient on top of an image

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/sibling"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        >
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/view_to_move"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/sibling"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/sibling"
        /></android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Rest of properties necessary for layout...
Important both properties app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/sibling" and app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/sibling"
Both must be inside of constraint.